# filtering/removing potential dangerous content from word files?

Tags: microsoft-word, security

Word (.docx) files can be [dangerous](https://superuser.com/questions/213818/are-docx-or-pdf-files-potentially-dangerous). I often receive word files from other people, which may or may not be safe. For the most part, I am only interested in getting the textual content, like text and tables with their format, equation objects, (and maybe images).

My question is:

Is there a safe, external way to remove dangerous contents (e.g. macros and other active contents) from word files without opening them in MS office?

The outcome I am looking for in the end, ideally, is a "static" word file that looks the same or similar in appearance, without any "active" content. Also, ideally, this solution should be external to allow batch processing of multiple word files, and to avoid the risk of opening untrusted file in office.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable their execution by using the Trust Center:

In Word's "Options", click on "Trust Center" and set the level of security you want. (Note that it automatically trusts "trusted locations" whatever that means - so consider whether you are fine with that.)

For more information see [this link](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-documents-7b4fdd2e-174f-47e2-9611-9efe4f860b12#bm2).